# JavaScript recursive setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, javascript-objects

I defined this class in JavaScript:

```
function Signal(lbl, ho, tag) {
    this.lbl = lbl;
    this.ho = ho;
    this.tag = tag;
    this.getstatus = function () {
        if (this.ho) {
            $.get('/get.cgi?' + this.tag + '=?0', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                setTimeout(this.getstatus, 1000);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Once getstatus is called, it should start calling itself with setTimout, but it doesn't! It only works one time.

If I use a function without a class, it works!

Please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Bad use of `this` try put something like `var self = this` right after the open if, and then call `self.getstatus`

Comment: On a pedantic note, Javascript doesn't have classes... Embrace the freedom of prototypes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when `getStatus` is invoked by the timer, `this` inside the method does not refer to the object, you can pass a custom value for `this` using `bind()`. Also note that in the ajax callback `this` refers to the ajax settings object.

```
function Signal(lbl, ho, tag) {
    this.lbl = lbl;
    this.ho = ho;
    this.tag = tag;
    this.getstatus = function () {
        if (this.ho) {
            var signal = this;
            $.get('/get.cgi?' + this.tag + '=?0', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                setTimeout(signal.getstatus.bind(signal), 1000);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I like to use a more expressive name than "self" (or "that"), in this case, *signal* seems appropriate so `var signal = this` and `signal.getstatus.bind(signal)` so it's clear what the bound *this* is. The correct *thisArg* can also be set using `setTimeout(function(){signal.getstatus()},1000)`.

Comment: @RobG: `signal` could be *any* Signal. `self` does (by convention) mean the current instance. Usually code is not misty enough that it's unclear which (of multiple instances) is meant.

Comment: @Bergi—similarly, *self* could be anything, the use of *signal* (or whatever *this* is an instance of) just gives a hint as to what it is. *self* might be appropriate for a method that might be called with different "classes" of objects at *this*.

Comment: I used thisSignal....